# Mocha test alway pass

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I want to test a Basic Authentication on my webpage with `mocha` :

```
describe('Test GET /messages', function(){

    describe('Test HTTP basic authentication', function(){

       it('should return 200 because right credentials', function(done){
           request.get(createCustomRequest(true, "/messages", "test", "test"), function(err, res, body){
               if (err) {
                   console.error(err)
               } else {
                    // Whatever, it will always pass
                    assert.equal(2400, res.statusCode);
               }
           }, done());
        });
  });

function createCustomRequest(withAuth, service, username, password){
    if(!withAuth){
        return {
            url: URL+service,
            followRedirect: false
        };
    } else {
        return {
            url: URL+service,
            followRedirect: false,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': createCredentials(username, password)
            }
        };
    }
}
```

From the code ahead, I do not understand why the test always pass. I think it is related to the `done()` callback.

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`done()` should be called within the callback to `request.get()`:

```
it('should return 200 because right credentials', function(done) {
  request.get(createCustomRequest(true, "/messages", "test", "test"), function(err, res, body){
    if (err) {
      done(err);
      return;
    }
    assert.equal(2400, res.statusCode);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Then, I got the classic message `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test`. Why?

Comment: Because the HTTP request is taking more than 2 seconds? Try increasing the timeout (`mocha -t 10000 ...`)

Comment: Totaly right. I think my docker env is kind of dead ... Thanks a lot!